# CMake generated project file to list external source

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, projects-and-solutions

please consider the following structure:

```
dev_root/
  \__ common/
        \__ inc/
        \__ src/
        \__ CMakeLists.txt
  \__ project1/
        \__ inc/
        \__ src/
        \__ CMakeLists.txt
  \__ project2/
        \__ inc/
        \__ src/
        \__ CMakeLists.txt
```

Project1 and Project2 are separated projects.
They both use common code.
I want to list (selectively) some common source files into each project's visual studio project file, so that I could edit them in IDE.
I don't want a standalone library for the common code.

For now I use relative paths, for example, in project1's cmake file:

```
set(_hdr
    inc/proj1.h
    ../common/inc/common1.h
)
set(_src
    src/proj1.cxx
    ../common/src/common1a.cxx
    ../common/src/common1b.cxx
)
source_group("common\\inc" FILES 
              ../common/inc/common1.h 
)
source_group("common\\src" FILES 
              ../common/src/common1a.cxx 
              ../common/src/common1b.cxx
)
source_group("inc" FILES inc/proj1.h)
source_group("src" FILES src/proj1.cxx)

add_executable( project1 ${_src} ${_hdr} )
```

This is not flexible - if ever I want to move folders around, all CMakeLists.txt must be reviewed and modified. 
Is there a more elegant way to de-couple the dependencies, or what is a better way to deal with common source files?

Any suggestions welcomed.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You may set variable to the path to 'common' folder, and use it for refer to files in it. So, whenever you need to move 'common' folder around, you need to edit only this variable.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(COMMON_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/common)
```

project1/CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(_hdr
    inc/proj1.h
    ${COMMON_DIR}/inc/common1.h
)
set(_src
    src/proj1.cxx
    ${COMMON_DIR}/src/common1a.cxx
    ${COMMON_DIR}/src/common1b.cxx
)
...
```